# Extract text outside an opening and closing curly brace "{}" in PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a file pattern, for example `{user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type}` and I have this to extract the values between an opening and closing curly brace `{}`

```
with
     inputs (str) as (
       select '{user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type}'
       from   dual
     )
select level as ord,
substr(str, instr(str, '{', 1, level) + 1, instr(str, '}', 1, level) - instr(str, '{', 1, level) - 1) as data
from   inputs
connect by level <= length(str) - length(replace(str, '{'))
;
```

which outputs this

```
ORD   DATA                                  
----- ----------
1     user                                   
2     yyyymmdd                               
3     type
```

In a separate column, I want to obtain this

```
ORD   STATIC SEGMENTS                                  
----- ----------
1     _                                   
2     _dailyreport.
```

but not sure how to get that. It basically represents every text not enclosed in a pair of opening and closing brace

Comment: Are expressions in curly braces always present at the beginning and at the end of the string? Are expressions in curly braces always separated by substrings of length at least one? In general, it would make the most sense to return all substrings not in curly braces, including before the first `{` and after the last `}`, and between braced expressions, even if some of those may be empty strings (`null` in Oracle). Separate question: can there also be "literal" curly braces in your strings, perhaps escaped somehow?

Comment: Are expressions in curly braces always present at the beginning and at the end of the string? - Yes. `{User}` will always be the first token, and `{Type}` will be last. 

Can there also be "literal" curly braces in your strings - No.

Comment: There may be other tokens like `{yyyymmdd}`, `{country_code}` etc in the middle of the string, along with the fixed part of the string (`_dailyreport.` in this case), not necessarily in any fixed order.

Comment: When we end up getting a file name that follows the pattern (Eg - `yorpa_20201001_dailyreport.json` in this case), we want to extract information by mapping them to the tokens through the static segments. Our final output (not in the scope of this question, but adding here for context) should be 
`1. user - yorpa 2. yyyymmdd - 20201001 3. type - json`

Comment: Your latest example doesn't have any curly braces in it, so what does it have to do with your question?

Comment: Correct, the latest comment is not in scope of the question. I was just trying to call out the bigger problem to solve - in case that makes a difference to this particular solution. I can delete that comment if it is making things more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If - as you say in a reply in the Comments section - the initial and final substrings will always be braced expressions, this should be easy. You are looking for the substrings between the n'th closing brace and the (n+1)'st opening brace; so you can use pretty much the same computation, modified accordingly.

```
with
     inputs (str) as (
       select '{user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type}'
       from   dual
     )
select level as ord,
substr(str, instr(str, '{', 1, level) + 1, 
       instr(str, '}', 1, level) - instr(str, '{', 1, level) - 1) as data,
substr(str, instr(str, '}', 1, level) + 1, 
       instr(str, '{', 1, level + 1) - instr(str, '}', 1, level) - 1) as static_segment
from   inputs
connect by level <= length(str) - length(replace(str, '{'))
;

ORD DATA       STATIC_SEGMENT    
--- ---------- ------------------
  1 user       _                 
  2 yyyymmdd   _dailyreport.     
  3 type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a recursive sub-query and simple string functions (you do not need slow regular expressions):

```sql
WITH bounds (str, start_pos, start_param, end_param, param_index) AS (
  SELECT str,
         1,
         INSTR(str, '{', 1),
         INSTR(str, '}', INSTR(str, '{', 1)),
         1
  FROM   inputs
UNION ALL
  SELECT str,
         end_param + 1,
         INSTR(str, '{', end_param + 1),
         INSTR(str, '}', INSTR(str, '{', end_param + 1)),
         param_index + 1
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  start_param > 0
  AND    end_param > 0
  AND    end_param < LENGTH(str)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY str SET str_order
SELECT str,
       param_index,
       CASE start_param
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(str, start_pos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(str, start_pos, start_param - start_pos)
       END AS static_segment,
       CASE 
       WHEN start_param = 0 OR end_param = 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTR(str, start_param + 1, end_param - start_param - 1)
       END AS data
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE inputs (str) AS
SELECT '{user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc{param1}def{param2}ghi{param3}jkl' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | STR | PARAM_INDEX | STATIC_SEGMENT | DATA |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | abc{param1}def{param2}ghi{param3}jkl | 1 | abc | param1 |
> | abc{param1}def{param2}ghi{param3}jkl | 2 | def | param2 |
> | abc{param1}def{param2}ghi{param3}jkl | 3 | ghi | param3 |
> | abc{param1}def{param2}ghi{param3}jkl | 4 | jkl |  |
> | {user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type} | 1 |  | user |
> | {user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type} | 2 | _ | yyyymmdd |
> | {user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type} | 3 | _dailyreport. | type |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ef487f70884dafd62b439111bd109ee)*

Answer (score 1):

Using `regexp_substr` and treating `{` and `}` as delimiters, you want the 4th word:

```
regexp_substr(str,'[^{}]+',1,4);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear. I wanted the full list of strings that are not enclosed by curly braces, not just the last string. In this case `_` and `_dailyreport.` are both relevant

Comment: So should the output be a column containing the values `user`,`yyyymmdd`,`_dailyreport.`,`type`?

Comment: No, it should be `_` and `_dailyreport.` because these are the texts not inside a pair of curly braces. `user`, `yyyymmdd` and `type` are all inside curly braces.

Comment: Do you really need to iterate over the file name, or is the format fixed enough that you can pick out the elements you want as in my example, just changing the final digit?

Comment: Not sure what it means by "format is fixed enough"...we just want all strings which are not enclosed by curly braces.

Comment: I mean files are often named in a fixed way like `accounting_loans_20210831_20210903.dat`, so in that example there are exactly 4 pieces of information, which may vary from day to day, but it will never be `accounting_loans_20210831_20210903_hatstand_banana.dat`. I've never seen a situation where it would be useful to make a list of all the elements in the filename without knowing how many there are. Say one day there are 8 strings not enclosed in curly braces. You make a list of them using a `connect by rownum <= regexp_count` query. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself! How? Replace curly brackets with another delimiter (such as semi-colon); the rest is then simple.

```
SQL> with
  2  inputs (str) as
  3    (select '{user}_{yyyymmdd}_dailyreport.{type}'
  4     from   dual
  5    ),
  6  replaced as
  7    (select trim(both ';' from replace(replace(str, '{', ';'), '}', ';')) val
  8     from inputs
  9    )
 10  select level ord,
 11         regexp_substr(val, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
 12  from replaced
 13  connect by level <= regexp_count(val, ';') + 1;

       ORD RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 user
         2 _
         3 yyyymmdd
         4 _dailyreport.
         5 type

SQL>
```